# How to debug randomly unresponsive react.js web page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have web page which is allmost whole in React.js therefore many classes and many external libraries are used.
The problem is sometimes (probably randomly) I get chrome error window that page is unresponsive. Its always when page is minimalized or on other not currently open tab.

When I click back to page tab or maximalize it, page is fully working and there is no unresponsivity.

I tried to run profiler and leave page in background but it never happens when profiler is running. I even left it for whole weekend and no crash has occured.

Also page is not loading anything in background from server until first user input but even then without touching page I get this weired chrome window with error.

How can I debug it?

Also this does not happen in firefox and I have not tested it yet in other broswers.

Comment: Have you checked Timeline in DevTools? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to reproduce a bug can be super frustrating.

The Chrome error page basically means you either have an infinite loop or a memory leak. Since you left the page over the weekend and it still worked, you can probably rule out a memory leak.

Adding testing to your application will flush out any infinite loops pretty quickly. Assuming you already have some basic unit testing, try adding some integration tests that invoke network calls.

In the end, even if you don't find this specific problem, you'll have some extra tests and will have narrowed the problem down further.

Comment: Might not have solved your problem, but is a very good response. Also, Google Analytics can help you find out which devices or browsers are screwing you up